# matlab saveas function results in empty plot

Tags: matlab, graph

The following code creates figure(2), figure(3) and figure(5) but the saveas function results in an empty file in windows 10. I have to run the code a second time in order for the saveas function to work? How to fix?

```
clear; clc;
x=linspace(0,1,5);
x
f=@(x) x.^3
plot(x,f(x),'c'); hold on
figure(2)
saveas(figure(2),'f','emf')

x=linspace(0,1,5);
x
g=@(x) x.^2
plot(x,g(x),'m'); hold on
figure(3)
saveas(figure(3),'g','emf')

x=linspace(0,1,5);
x
f=@(x) x.^3; 
g=@(x) x.^2; 
plot(x,f(x),'r',x,g(x),'b'); hold on
figure(5)
saveas(figure(5),'fg2.emf')
```

The following code is similar and runs successfully the first time.

```
x=linspace(0,1,5);
x
f=@(x) x.^3; 
plot(x,f(x),'r'); hold on;
figure(4)
g=@(x) x.^2; 
plot(x,g(x),'b'); hold off
figure(4)
saveas(figure(4),'fg.emf')
```

I would like to plot f and g using

```
plot(x,f(x),'r',x,g(x),'b')
```

Why is this happening?  Thank you in advance.

Sincerely,  Mary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order is wrong, lets take the last example:

```
%first generate the output you want to plot
x=linspace(0,1,5);
f=@(x) x.^3;
g=@(x) x.^2;  
%where do you want to plot it comes first
figure(4)
%and then the plot call
plot(x,f(x),'r'); 
hold on;
plot(x,g(x),'b'); 
hold off
%now you can save it
saveas(figure(4),'fg.emf')
```